# How to re-size screen size over serial terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, resize, termios

I'm developing serial terminal sw and trying to resolve asynchronous screen size.
Below is in detail

- There are modem_[a,b] and modem_a's uart1, _b's uart0 are connected(Main console port of both is uart0).
- serial_app on modem_a attempts to access to modem_b via serial line.
- serial_app uses termios library

And it's possible to serial-access to modem_b then it provides terminal service like putty.
[image]

But I change console window size then it starts asynchronous display.
[image]

However, I execute `resize` command then it becomes fixed.

So I checked `SIGWINCH` and it was triggered on modem_a but not on modem_b. And I've looked for how to pass SIGWINCH through serial terminal or cause SIGWINCH over modem_b controlling terminal settings like ioctl_tty(), escape sequence(\e[8;$Height;$Width, ...) , and so on...

Eventually I failed..

I'd like to maintain synchronous display whenever I change window size.

So you guys, Do you have a solution? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I was unable to automatically synchronize window size and display on serial terminal. It's just there is not a mechanism on serial terminal.

So, we should manually synchronize window by resize command on that.

Reference:

[image: Ref1]
source : http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2009-May/069226.html

[image]
source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console